# Selenium Grid Node can't register to HUB via VPN

Tags: selenium, vpn, selenium-grid, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have got a VPN set up like a VPN server running in Oracle Cloud - Oracle Linux 8; the client is my local VM - Manjaro Linux. The VPN connection works just fine.

My Selenium Hub is running on the same Oracle Cloud instance, Selenium Node is running on the same local Manjaro VM, so they're on the same network, as needed.

Starting Selenium Hub works, but when starting Node it says:

> [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: No route to host (Host unreachable)

I started Host like:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

It says:

```
>13:40:52.933 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
>13:40:53.079 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
>13:40:53.566:INFO::main: Logging initialized @949ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
>13:40:53.763 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
>13:40:53.766 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://10.9.0.1:4444/grid/register/
>13:40:53.767 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://10.9.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

I started Node like:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.9.0.1:4444
```

(10.9.0.1 is the VPN given IP of Selenium Host)

and it says:

```
>16:16:25.675 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
>16:16:25.950 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 31862
>2021-07-15 16:16:26.077:INFO::main: Logging initialized @754ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
>16:16:26.368 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
>16:16:26.520 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 31862
>16:16:26.521 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
>16:16:26.629 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
>16:16:27.092 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.No route to host (Host unreachable)
>16:16:27.102 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://10.9.0.1:4444/grid/register
>16:16:27.266 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: No route to host (Host unreachable)
```

Since VPN works fine, so the 2 machines are on the same network, as needed for Selenium Grid, I have no clue what can be wrong, especially after so many hours of Googling, even here on Stack Overflow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please review the below post, this might be useful
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276613/selenium-grid-cant-manage-nodes-in-the-private-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276613/selenium-grid-cant-manage-nodes-in-the-private-network)
Thanks,
Anupam

Comment: Sorry, it's not. Already seen this, but it talks about VPN as a solution for a somewhat similar problem, but I already have VPN in place, and otherwise than for Selenium Grid, it's working fine.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your VCN and linux instance? Ports open? in other words security rules and firewall configurations

Comment: it seems that the port 4444 is not open

Comment: Is your Manjaro Linux outside of OCI? If yes, OCI needs to know where to route the return traffic through a route rule in associated route table. Otherwise, even if forward traffic hits your Hub, return won't.

You can verify this first by checking if traffic hits OCI by verifying OCI VCN Flow Logs and/or TCPDUMP. If it hits, then the missing route rule (if it is) could be the cause. 

if the traffic doesn't even hit OCI, then check the routing at source.

Regardless, verify if security list rules + IPTABLES rules are in sync.